Inconsistent lead test results with allegedly identical chemistries
I am trying to remove paint from some brick that was likely painted in the 60s or 70s. Went ahead and ordered those cheap unbranded lead tests and got a hit. Just to be sure, I got a pack of more expensive tests from Lowes that unfortunately had the same chemistry. This pack also showed lead. Finally ordered scitus tests that require a vinegar dip, and the scitus test had a negative result. The scitus tests are also sodium rhodizonate and should be identical hypothetically.
I tested them all on a lead fishing weight for control and they all lit up. Trying to understand what is causing the difference in results between allegedly identical tests (except for the priming of the first two with a dry acid)
I am trying to find an alternate chemistry test currently and I'm open to suggestions.



The problem with removing lead paint, is you want to collect all paint chips/dust, so no one can eat/get them in their bodies.  Do that and wear eye protection and a good mask and remove away.  Inside usually just need to seal the area and wash down everything after.  Outside is more of a problem sealing.  Do not want lead dust/chips falling on the ground or going onto your neighbours.

That's fine. I'm just wondering why the lead tests are inconsistent and if there is even lead on the bricks, or if it is some other metal.

Most tests are not 100% all the time.  Even testing if electrical circuit has power off, some times you will get a test that shows power on that circuit.  Usually what is called phantom voltage and won't hurt you, but stills makes you test further to make sure.

How do you know how identical your samples are? Percentage of the paint that is lead paint will vary depending on when and how it was painted over, and amount of lead in the paint will vary from batch to batch and color to color. I'm not surprised you are seeing some variation. What really matters is whether the test says there is any lead present or not; if there is, take appropriate precautions.

Could be you have many layers of paint, and not all are as "lead-ey" as others.

I tested the same 4 cm^2 area of the same brick for all three tests (see yellow staining on test brick). Did so multiple times. Looking for a chemistry explanation of why the tests are different

The unbranded and homesafe swabs just lit up on a penny, the scitus did not. Looks like copper and/or zinc trigger the tests. Will report back when the alternate chemistry arrives

When I understand the results..

I agree that the question isn't opinion-based, but I will say that what you're asking skirts the home improvement realm somewhat. It's really a science question, and due to the unknown and potentially manifold compounds in the paint and test kits, we're not equipped to answer it within the site's stated scope. Good luck.

If you tested the same area several times, wouldn't we assume that this contaminated the subsequent tests?

Second chemistry came in, surface appears negative for lead. Looks like the cheap swabs that were predipped in acid probably had a pH that was too high and are reacting with zinc oxide in the old paint layer.
